# New class member of static library missing after compilation

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, static

Good morning,

I´m facing a very strange problem on which I haven´t found a solution yet.
I hope someone could give me a clou.

I´m having a class compiled to a static lib.
I´m using this class in a simple console program to perform tests on that class.

The class worked like a charm until I added a new data member (std::string) to the class.
Even if I don´t use that string I get strange errors when the dtor of the class is called (access violation when the string got no value or bufferoverflow when the string got initialized).

Debugging the class showed that the new std::string is not present though a the old members are there.

I even tried to initialize that string in the ctor (strLPath.str("Appletree")) and output it before the dtor.
The output of the string shows something like "Ap   tre  ".

When I remove that new string everything is fine again.

Can somebody help me ?

Thx for any answers in advance.

Phil

Comment: Are you sure you did a full, clean rebuild? Can you show the relevant code? Can you reproduce the error with a small example?

Comment: Please post a narrowed down sample of the source code. Seeing the source code people can help you better than through a pageful of words.

Comment: I don't think the source code will be very useful here. It sounds like a partial build problem, as Space_C0wb0y suggests. Parts of the program are still using the old class definition. Rebuild *everything* from scratch and try again.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y Yes I tried that (ctrl+alt+f7 in both the lib and the calling programm)

Comment: @Phil: I can't find ctrl+alt+f7 in Microsoft's keyboard shortcuts at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx. What does it mean? And are you sure it means what you think it does?

Comment: @TonyK It means rebuild solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thx to everybody who were spending time thinking about my problem.

Anyway - i solved it last night.

When I created the test program I was a lazy fool it seems.

Instead of including the original header, I copied it to the test project.

Don´t know what got into me that eve.

Sorry for wasting your time!

Regards,
Phil